# Timeline for Implementing UX Process

Tags: process, ux-integration, planning

I am in the process of presenting and implementing a brand new UI/UX process.  I have gotten buy in for the proposed phases of the design process.  But I am getting timeline questions regarding how long it would take to implement the full process or how much could be done within a 6month window and how to plan out a 6month window.  I know this is super subjective but has anyone had any experience with anything similar? Or how long each step in a design process could take to nail down/implement?

Thanks!

Comment: You say that you got buy in for "the design process", then you received questions on implementing "the full process". What else are you considering to be part of the "full" process? Also, I bought a book a while ago (still haven't read it) that might be exactly on topic for what you're trying to implement: [Lean UX](https://www.leanuxbook.com/).

Comment: I've heard of this but haven't read it yet.  Thanks for the recommendation!

Answer (score 3):

You will need to start with the MVP features prioritised. Then develop a Gantt chart based on the complexity of the feature. If there is not enough time, you will need to compromise somewhere. Therefore it is important to mark MVP and high priority features from the beginning. Break down the product into as many features as possible for better estimates (for that you may need some low-fi sketches, to get a better idea of the map). Discuss this with the client (they may want to include/exclude something) and sign the deal that these are what will be included in the first phase.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

**At first, you need to define a list of task and who is responsible for the changes. After this, you should ask a deadline for each part of the process for each responsible. If you will do everything must be easier.**

I don't know if is exactly this what you are looking for but I create a sheet to organize all alterations for a year. How I did it:

- Organized the tasks in groups like (urgent bad performance, product page, category page, home, header...).
- Added * to the required task to met the goal of CVR increase.
- Split the working hours for each task in Research, Wireframe, Design, Development and Test to force the managers to understand and respect the minimum required process.
- Estimate Expected increase for that change based on what track and how to track it.

And I created some other columns to help my management and to complete with the managers and other members of the team.

Maybe this is not the best way but is working perfectly for my current project.

[image]

Comment: Great idea, thanks for the help!

Comment: @Jeremy If my answer is a good solution for your case, please check as the right answer and upvote if is really useful for you.